# Bootstrap Carousel component overlaps with navbar

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I am trying to include carousel component in my web page but it is overlapping with the nav bar. I tried to remove the navbar but the carousel component disappears. The html code is written as template for django. I have checked the image import in console and the image is taken from source folder. There is no problem in the source folder.

Here is the html code for carousel component a.html:

```
{%extends 'common.html'%} {%block content%}
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/static/images/home/1.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/static/images/home/2.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/static/images/home/3.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/static/images/home/4.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/static/images/home/5.JPG" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for common.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/frontend/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
</head>
  <body>
    {%load static%}
    <div id="navbar">
      <script src="{% static 'javascript/Navbar.js' %}"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
      {%block content%} {%endblock%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide live example in codepen or jsfiddle or https://repl.it/languages/django

Comment: here is the link https://repl.it/repls/GhostwhiteCavernousApplication

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 problem,

1. You haven't active class in your `carousel-item`
2. There is no `ul` in `carousel-indicators`, its `ol`

Here working example of it https://repl.it/repls/SoggySpecificIntroductory